# Appending a list built using conditional and appended values to a list of lists

Tags: list, python-3.x, csv, iteration

I'm currently working with two large csv files of numerical data.  One such csv, which we will call X, is composed entirely of numerical data for test subjects.  The columns of a are arranged as health measurements like so (id, v1,v2,v3,v4).  I am trying to take this information and create a list of lists where each list contains the information for a single person i.e as in this fashion:

```
X=[['1','a','b','c','d'],
   ['1','e','f','g','h'],
   ['2','i','j','k','l'],
   ['3','m','n','o','p']]

listoflists=[ [['1','a','b','c','d'],['1','e','f','g','h']],  #first row
              ['2','i','j','k','l'],   #second
              ['3','m','n','o','p'] ]  #third
```

(let me know if i should edit the formatting: i wanted to present X as columns for readability.  On list of lists I just ran out of room, so listolists = [ a,b,c], where a is the first row, b is the second, and c is third
I've tried something to the effect of this, but my biggest issue is I'm not sure where to create the list of those entities with matching data and then append it to the "master list".

```
#create a set that holds the values of the subject ids.
    ids=list(set([item[0] for item in X]))
    #create the list of lists i want 
    listolists=[]
    for value in ids: 
        listolists.append(sublist)
        for i in range(len(X))
            sublist=[]           #I'm not sure where to create sublists of 
                                  #matching data and append to listolists
            if value == X[i][0]
               sublist.append(X[i]
```

All help is appreciated.  thanks.

Comment: Are the `IDs` guaranteed to be consecutive - if so - you can use `itertools.groupby` - if not - you can use a `collections.defaultdict`...

Comment: thanks for the reply!  and they are in this case!  I was looking for a more general way to do so just in those cases where the data is not so nice.

Comment: not quite sure what you mean by "general way" - `[list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(X, lambda L: L[0])]` should work though?

Comment: for any work of this kind on CSV files in python you should have a look at `pandas` - the same `groupby(column_name)` exists there but it makes dealing with the data much easier

Comment: My bad.  I meant just in case the ids or whatever variable I'm "sorting by" isn't consecutive or if I want to build a list based on some other condition other than equality.

Comment: @MattiLyra Thanks for the reply.  I'll have to take a look.  Is the panda list iterable-say if I want to convert these lists in the master list  to floats and then apply some matrix algebra to each list?

Comment: Have you done it yet? I'll try helping you if not

Comment: i have not been able to get the code working in the fashion in my op, but i have been looking at itertools documentation. for the past ten or so!

if you have any suggestions i'd love to hear them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something:

```
X =[
    ['1','a','b','c','d'],
    ['1','e','f','g','h'],
    ['2','i','j','k','l'],
    ['3','m','n','o','p'],
    ]

numbers = {x[0] for x in X}

output = []

for num in sorted(numbers):
    new_list = [sub_list for sub_list in X if sub_list[0] == num]
    output.append(new_list)

print(output)

...


[[['1', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['1', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']],
 [['2', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']],
 [['3', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p']]]
```

If you need to 2nd and third list not nested like the first let me know

**EDIT** - for exact format specified in your question

```
X =[
    ['1','a','b','c','d'],
    ['1','e','f','g','h'],
    ['2','i','j','k','l'],
    ['3','m','n','o','p'],
    ]

numbers = {x[0] for x in X}

output = []

for num in sorted(numbers):
    new_list = [sub_list for sub_list in X if sub_list[0] == num]
    if len(new_list) > 1:
        output.append(new_list)
    else:
        output.append((new_list)[0])

print(output)
```

Comment: No problem, if you are using this with massive data sets you may want to change the comprehension to stop when the number changes as at the moment it does a full iteration. Please select a best answer if you are happy with it. Cheers